TikzPicture creating block diagram for anti-windup PI Controller
I am having some difficults on creating a block diagram for a PI Controller with anti windup. I would like it to be something like this, including the anti windup rectangle. Moreover, I was trying to add a saturation block by the end of the system, but I couldn't find documentation for it.

For now, I have something like this, but everytime I try to connect the blocks, I get a timed out:

The code is below, but I don't know if it will be useful:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,shapes}

% Estilos para o TikZ
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line cap=round,line join=round]
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2.5cm,>=latex']
    % Nodes
    \node [input] (input) {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (proportional) {$K_p$};
    \node [block, below of=proportional] (integral) {$K_i$};
    \node [sum, right of=integral] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum2] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
    \node [block, below of=integrator] (anti) {$K_{aw}$};
    \node [block, right of=proportional, node distance=2.5cm] (saturation) {SAT};
    \node [output, right of=saturation, node distance=2.5cm] (output) {};
    
    % Connections
    \draw [->] (input) -- node {$R(s)$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- (proportional);
    \draw [->] (proportional) -- (saturation);
    \draw [->] (saturation) -- node {$U(s)$} (output);
    
    \draw [->] (integral) -- (sum2) -- (integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- (sum2);
    \draw [->] (anti) -| (integrator);

    % Feedback path
    \node [coordinate, below of=input, node distance=2cm] (measurements) {};
    \draw [->] (output) |- (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} node [near end] {$Y_m(s)$} (sum);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Diagrama de blocos de um controlador PI com anti-\textit{windup}.}
\label{fig:antiwindup}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TEX.SE! Please make your code compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Block for saturation symbol you need create yourself. BTW, you use depreciate syntax for defining tikzpicture  options. Instead of \tikzstyle, you should use \tikzset.

Just some ideas for starting point how you can define elements of your sheme and than draw it:
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds, 
                calc, 
                positioning, 
                quotes}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 8mm,
arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}},
box/.style = {fill=gray, rounded corners,
              minimum height=9mm, minimum width=12mm,
              inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt, text=white
                  },
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\scriptsize},
every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt},
sat/.style = {box,
    path picture={
        \draw[thick, white, sharp corners]
    ($(\ppbb.south west) + ( 1ex,1ex)$) --
         ($(\ppbb.south) + (-1ex,1ex)$) --
         ($(\ppbb.north) + (1ex,-1ex)$) --
         ($(\ppbb.north east) + (-1ex,-1ex)$);
                        }% end path picture
                    },
sum/.style = {circle, minimum size=6mm, fill=gray, outer sep=0pt},
                    ]
\node (U) [box] {$K_p$};
\node (V) [box, below=of U] {$K_I$};
\node (X) [sum, right=of U] {};
\node (Y) [sat, label=below:Atuator, right=of X] {};
\node (Z) [box,at={(V -| X)}] {$\frac{1}{s}$};
%
\draw[arr]  (U) edge[pos=0.9, "+"] (X) 
            (X) edge (Y) 
            (Y) to ++ (1,0) node[right] {$Y(s)$};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \fill[gray!30]   ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}] Y.north west) 
                                -| ([shift={(1mm,-1mm)}] Y.east |- Z.south) coordinate (AW)
                                -| ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}] Z.north west)  -| cycle; 
\node[inner sep=0pt, label=above left:Anti-Windup] at (AW) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


of course, above picture is quite far from what your desired picture should be, however, contain all elements  that you can extend it to desired form.
Edit:
In spars time I draw your complete desired diagram:
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds, 
                calc,           % for simbols in boxes
                positioning, 
                quotes}         % for labels on edges
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 4mm and 3mm,
arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}},
box/.style = {fill=gray, rounded corners,
              minimum height=9mm, minimum width=12mm,
              inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt, text=white
                  },
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.2pt, outer sep=0pt},    
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\scriptsize},
every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize, label distance=0pt, inner sep=2pt},
sat/.style = {box,
    path picture={
        \draw[thick, white, sharp corners]
    ($(\ppbb.south west) + ( 1ex,1ex)$) --
         ($(\ppbb.south) + (-1ex,1ex)$) --
         ($(\ppbb.north) + (1ex,-1ex)$) --
         ($(\ppbb.north east) + (-1ex,-1ex)$);
                 }% end path picture
             },
sum/.style = {circle, minimum size=6mm, fill=gray, outer sep=0pt,    
    path picture={
        \draw[thick, white,]
    ($(\ppbb.west)  + (1ex,0)$)  -- ($(\ppbb.east) + (-1ex,0)$) 
    ($(\ppbb.north) + (0,-1ex)$) -- ($(\ppbb.south) + (0,1ex)$);
                 }% end path picture
             },
                    ]
%%
\coordinate[label=left:$R(s)$]  (in-1);
\node (n1) [sum, right=of in-1] {};
\node (n2) [dot, right=of n1]   {};
\coordinate[belo=of in-1 |- n1.south,
            label=left:$Y_m(s)$] (in-2);
    \draw[arr]  (in-2) -| (n1);     
%%
\node (n3) [box, right=of n2] {$K_p$};
\node (n4) [box, below=of n3]   {$K_i$};
\node (n5) [sum, right=of n4]   {};
\node (n6) [box, right=of n5]   {$\frac{1}{s}$};
%%
\node (n7) [sum, right=of n6.east |- n3]   {};
\node (n8) [dot, right=of n7]   {};
\node (n9) [sat, right=of n8, 
            label=below:Atuator] {};
\node (n10) [dot, right=of n9]   {};
\coordinate[label=right:$Y(s)$,
            right=of n10]        (out);
%%
\node (n11) [box, below=of n6]   {$K_{aw}$}; 
\node (n12) [sum, right=of n7 |- n11]  {};
%%%%
\draw[arr]  (in-1) edge[pos=0.9, "+"] (n1)
            (n1) edge   (n3) 
            (n3) edge[pos=0.95, "+"] (n7)
            (n7) edge   (n9)
            (n9)  to    (out);
            %
\draw[arr]  (n2) |- (n4);
\draw[arr]  (n4) edge[pos=0.9, "+"] (n5) 
            (n5) edge   (n6)
            (n6) -| (n7);
\node[label=below left:+] at (n7) {};
            %
\draw[arr]  (n10) |- (n12)
            (n12) edge["$E_{\textsc{SAT}}$"]  (n11)
            (n8)  edge[pos=0.95, "+"]  (n12) node[pos=0.95,label=+]{};
\draw[arr]  (n11) -| (n5) node[pos=0.8, label=+] {};
%%%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \fill[gray!30]   ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}] n9.north west) 
                                -| ([shift={(1mm,-1mm)}] n10.east |- n11.south) coordinate (AW)
                                -| ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}] n5.west |- n6.north)  
                                -| ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}] n11.north west)  
                                -| cycle; 
\node[inner sep=0pt, label=above left:Anti-Windup] at (AW) {};
            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for your help

Great, +1, and the second Q&A in a row about circuitikz where it's frankly better not to use circuitikz at all.
